# Trying to use Ajax for my AddToCart Function (Using a form in a Foreach)

Tags: c#, html, ajax, html.beginform

So far, this will add only the first item to the cart and stay on the same page. Each page has at least 3 items which it creates a new form with each time. The other products it wont add to the cart and it redirects me to the Home Index View. I am using Ajax to submit the form. The error message (only when adding the first item to the cart) pops up instead of the success message, so something is not going through right. This is what I have so far.....

View:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
         <a href="@Url.Action("Details","Products", new { id = item.ProductID 
           })" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">View details</a>

         <div id="MessageContent"></div>

  @using (Html.BeginForm
         ("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @productID = item.ProductID, Id = "myForm" }))
             {
              @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Where(p => p.ProductID == 
               item.ProductID).FirstOrDefault().ProductID)

          <input type="submit" onclick="addToCart(1)" value="Add To Cart" 
          class="btn btn-primary" />                                                   
 }
}
```

Ajax (on view):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {           
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#MessageContent')
           .html("<div class='alert alert-info'> Adding to cart...</div>")
            $.ajax({               
                url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Home")',               
                type: 'POST',            
                data: $(this).serialize(),               
                success: function (e) {                
                    $('#MessageContent')
                        .html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Item added to cart</div>");                                    
                },               
               error: function (e) {              
                    $('#MessageContent').html("<div class='alert alert-warning'>Oops...Some error Occured.</div>");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
       public void AddToCart(int productID)

        {
            ////Create the Shell Local Shopping Cart
            Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartViewModel> shoppingCart = null;

            //Check the global shopping cart
            if (Session["cart"] != null)
            {
                //if it has stuff in it, reassign to the local
                shoppingCart = (Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartViewModel>)Session["cart"];
            }
            else
            {
                //create an empty Local Version
                shoppingCart = new Dictionary<int, ShoppingCartViewModel>();
            }

            //get the product being displayed in the view
           Product product = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == productID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (product == null)
            {
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                //title is valid
                ShoppingCartViewModel item = new ShoppingCartViewModel(1, product);

                //if the item is already in the cart just increase the qty
                if (shoppingCart.ContainsKey(product.ProductID))
                {
                    shoppingCart[product.ProductID].Qty += 1;
                }
                else //add the item to the cart
                {
                    shoppingCart.Add(product.ProductID, item);
                }
                //now that the item has been added to the local cart, 
                //update the session cart with the new item/qty
                Session["cart"] = shoppingCart;    
            }              
        }
```

UPDATE: I just fixed the error Message by deleting the datatype: 'json' from the ajax function.

Comment: Your redirect to Index view is commented out. Yet it still redirects you? Have you checked the console for any scripting errors?

Comment: It is commented out since its in a Void ActionResult. It doesnt allow you to return anything. When it was just Public it wouldn't reset the count in the AddToCart due to it just wanting to return the same view. I'm assuming it's redirecting me to the Index by default as these views are in my Home Controller. I'll look to see what the Console comes up with.

Comment: The console says "Found 3 elements with non-unique id" however in the input values and the form values  have the unique product id in the html below the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have it figured out. Rookie Mistake... I was using a unique '#myform' id on each form so it was no longer being used after the first form was submitted. The MessageContent id, however, I could not get to pop up without displaying on all the form or only one. That's not important though as I can just remove that portion.